# Suppressing text when printing in LaTeX

Tags: printing, latex, pdflatex

I want to include a blank page in my document with only the text "(this page intentionally left blank)". I would like to suppress the text when the document is viewed by a computer, but I still want the text to print on paper (via PDF) with said text. Is there a good way to achieve this effect? Are things of this sort even supported in the PDF format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does "viewed by a computer" mean? I think the computer will always see the entire document. If you mean some text will be visible only when printed, and not onscreen, I don't think PDF can do that. BUt you could use conditional compilation to produce two versions, one for print and one for screen. Some pointers are [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=conditional)

Comment: PDF can definitely do it. I know because hyperlinks come out differently on screen and in print (for example). However, I don't know how one would do it. I recommend that the OP post in the dedicated [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) where no tex-related question is too small!

Comment: Using a Ugly Hack one may be able to change the colors in a dummy hyperref link so that it is black on print and white on screen. You'd have to play around with the options to the hyperref package....